# set lable to elements created by createElement method in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hello All,

I'm looking for someone who can tell me **how to set a label to an element** created by **createElement()** method in **zend form.**

I want to **create an array of input elements with label**.

Thanks In Adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...how to set a label to an element created by createElement() method in zend form

```
$form->createElement('text', 'someElement', array(
    'label' => 'Some label',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1, If an element has already been created and added to a form and you want to change the label later.  Grab the element and use the setLabel method on it:

```
<?php
$myForm->getElement('lastName')->setLabel('Surname');
?>
```